# Pagination on yii grid view

Tags: yii

I have a "booster.widgets.TbActiveForm" where on clicking on "search" button (along with the form values) a "booster.widgets.TbGridView" is being populated.Initially grid is okay with the values.But clicking on the pagination link there is no data coming to show the next page details on grid.

I can not find the suitable solutions for this.Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

here is my controller -

```
public function actiongetChartData($service_id, 
           $event_time_from = null, 
           $event_time_to = null, 
               $mode = null)
{ 
     Yii::app()->getComponent('booster');
     $model = new ApiSiriStatistics('search'); 
     $model->unsetAttributes(); 
     if (isset($_GET['ApiSiriStatistics'])) $model->attributes = $_GET['ApiSiriStatistics']; 
     $this->renderPartial('populategridchart', $populategridchart_arr, false, true); 
}
```

Comment: show your controller/action and gridview code

Comment: hi scaisEdge, thanks for the reply.I am bit late. sorry for that.

Comment: but i can not show you the code due to charcter limit.

Comment: here is my controller -  public function actiongetChartData($service_id, $event_time_from = null, $event_time_to = null, $mode = null){
        Yii::app()->getComponent('booster');        
        $model = new ApiSiriStatistics('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes(); 
        if (isset($_GET['ApiSiriStatistics']))
            $model->attributes = $_GET['ApiSiriStatistics'];
        
       $this->renderPartial('populategridchart', $populategridchart_arr, false, true);

Comment: I have update you question with your controller but i can't understand your code .. i'm sorry .